# If $xR_1y$ if $x^2 + y^2$ is divisible by $5$, is the relation transitive?

Tags: relations

Been asked to prove if this is/isn't transitive. Not sure where to start on if it is transitive or not. Also by proving it is/isn't, do I simply need to give an example where it is/isn't true?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.SE. Please use [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/570189) to improve readability and increase your chances to get meaningful answers.

Comment: To prove it's not transitive one example will suffice. To prove it is transitive you need an algebraic argument starting from the assumption that $x$ is related to $y$ and $y$ to $z$.

Comment: is that example transitive?

Comment: **Hint:** $R$ is symmetric, but not reflexive

Comment: Thank you but I knew that! Transitive is the problem here, I don't know what it means here. I only know with > or <

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R$ is transitive if, whenever $x R y$ and $y R z$, we have $x R z$.  Remembering what the relation means, the question you need to answer is: whenever $x^2 + y^2$ is divisible by 5 and $y^2 + z^2$ is divisible by 5, is $x^2 + z^2$ divisible by 5?

To prove the relationship is transitive, you need to show this is always true.  To prove it is not transitive, you need to find $x, y, z$ such that it's not true - that is, with $x^2 + y^2$ divisible by 5, $y^2 + z^2$ divisible by 5, and $x^2 + z^2$ not divisible by 5.

Comment: Got you! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

To prove it isn't true you need one example where it fails but to prove it you have to show it is true for all possible pairs, which means you need algebra.

Play around with some examples of xRy and yRz.

Comment: I don't get what transitive means in this example. I get symmetric and reflexive but not transitive here.

Comment: Transitive would mean if $x R y$ and $y R z$ then $x R z$.  This relation is **not** reflexive, e.g. it's not true that $1R1$.

Comment: A relation is transitive if xRy and yRz implies xRz.

Comment: I didn't mean I got that it was reflexive, I got that I understood what it meant here. I know the definition of transitive but having problems applying it here

Comment: I suggest you find a pair of (I presume) real numbers that are related and work from there.